# Расшифровка в нормальный текст (transfer-encoding)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Вот один сайт курлю. А там transfer-encoding в заголовках. Как можно раскодировать в нормальный текст? Уже и base64, iconv, что не экспериментировал, но все `��[[s�V�~�~�1�Ɉ$H�,�`. Но если в браузере просмотреть исходник, то все отображает нормально, еще гуглил, что оно сжимает g-zip. Кто с подобным сталкивался, как вы решили такую проблему?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальная практика сжать ответ gzip'ом, а гуглить надо было лучше :)

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не совсем уверен, но по моему мнению, виноват не transfer-encoding, а кодировка страницы.

Поэтому посмотрите в какой кодировке у вас сама страница и сделайте Windows-1251.

```
$html = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251//IGNORE', $html);
```

как-то так. Вместо 'utf-8' - надо написать вашу кодировку.

Comment: Проблема в том, что неизвестно, как закодированый текст раскодировать.